# PowerQuery Get Excel Named Variable Which is NOT a Table

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have a named variable in Excel, which not on the workbook itself, which I want to pass to a power query function.

I have been trying to understand how to do so. The only things I found were making use of Excel Table objects.
What if it is not a range at all, just a value, string, whatever which is only stored on name manager?

Do I need to go and put in on the workbook and transform it into a table? I didn't want to have that table editable since I don't need that...

Or can I get access to Excel's Name Manager to fetch a (normal) variable there ?

Thanks !

[image: Name Manager Example]

(In this example, in VBA I would do something like: ThisWorkbook.Names("This_one").Value)

Comment: As far as I know, it has to be in a table (or just a sheet for an external workbook).

Comment: don't think you can

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-used-named-cells-parameter-inputs-power-query-wyn-hopkins), from Wyn Hopkins, looks like it might be relevant to your question.

Comment: This is the closest you can do. But File.contents doesn't seem to fetch non cell name manager data.